# Testing Payment Processing Feature

Tags: python, database, web, payment-processing

I believe this question is probably outside of the scope of SO, but I was wondering what the best practice is for testing a payment processing feature?

For any feature developed, it's been relatively easy to test, if not through unit testing than through a front-end walkthrough, but with this, I'm at a bit of a loss, as I have not done this before.

What is suggested here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most payment processors have a sandbox/developers account where you can process transactions in a test mode so you can fully test them as if you were in a live environment.

Comment: Thank you for the response, could you please share a couple links of example payment processors that do this? Thanks.

Comment: [Authorize.Net has a developer account](http://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/) and [Paypal has a sandbox](https://developer.paypal.com/).